# Apple Push Notification Service - Does iOS keep an open connection to every registered APNS server?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

If I understand correctly, each application that registers as an APNS provider, basically forces the iPhone to keep a live connection to a specific server.
If so, doesn't it mean that the more apps I use (that register APNS), the more battery drain I will experience?

Would it not be wiser of Apple to allow developers to tap into a big server cluster that will distribute notifications to all devices in the world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always thought the Push Notification would work through SMS. But that wouldn't work with devices that do not have a phone system but Wifi only.

But in any case, even if iOS just polls, I'd think that it's all going to one central server (pool) from Apple, which will manage all requests as the message center.

This isn't a proper answer, just assumptions, but maybe someone else can confirm this or at least show where I'm wrong.

Comment: This is correct, each developer pushes their notifications to Apple's servers over SSL/TLS, apple then handles pushing the data down to the device.

Comment: I realize this is an old post, but just a little on what I know: When I test push notifications for my apps, they show up instantly so I don't think it is simply polling, it could be more complicated, maybe it polls until it gets a notification but then it keeps an open connection for a short period afterwards in case more notifications come in, then it times back out to polling the servers as to save battery.

Answer (score 1):

iOS keeps only one connection to APN server for every apps on device when it is available internet connection, so the battery does not drain more with each new application. That's it!